# Vs Code Extension Development, Default code doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying learn write vs code extension but default code doesn't work. How can I fix?

(node:10714) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use `Code Helper (Plugin) --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

I tried just run, I didn't make any changes.

```
// The module 'vscode' contains the VS Code extensibility API
// Import the module and reference it with the alias vscode in your code below
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

// This method is called when your extension is activated
// Your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    // Use the console to output diagnostic information (console.log) and errors (console.error)
    // This line of code will only be executed once when your extension is activated
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "vscode-translator-pro" is now active!');

    // The command has been defined in the package.json file
    // Now provide the implementation of the command with registerCommand
    // The commandId parameter must match the command field in package.json
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('vscode-translator-pro.helloWorld', () => {
        // The code you place here will be executed every time your command is executed
        // Display a message box to the user
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from Visual Studio Code Translator!');
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

// This method is called when your extension is deactivated
export function deactivate() {}
```

Comment: ignore that warning, some lib is not updated anymore

Comment: A warning is just a warning, which won't make the extension "doesn't work". What exactly happened and did you see "Hello World from Visual Studio Code Translator" showed?

Comment: Hello World command doesn't work.